# How to create a delayed CAAnimation that can be cancelled and/or reverted while playing?

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, caanimation

I have a layer that I want to show when the user does an action, and hide after he is done. The layer is then shown again if the user does the action again.

In order for the UI to not go berserk with animations, I want:

- that the fadeout animation only starts after one second (and is cancelled if the user does the action before it has started)
- the the fadein animation to show the layer starts from the current fadeout opacity if the user is doing action before the layer has disappeared

what is the best way to do this?

I tried this, but this won't work properly (lot of noise with the layer blinking ):

```
- (void)hideHintLayer:(bool)hide
{
  if(hide)
  {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.0f;
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.keyPath = @"opacity";
    animation.fromValue = @(1.0f);
    animation.toValue = @(0.0f);
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
  }
  else
  {
    layer.opacity = 1.0f;
  }
}
```

Comment: on which version on ios are u ?

Comment: I use iOS6, is there a difference for this with iOS5?

Comment: no - I was thinking to recommend u using block based animation on UIView but it will not work on layer.

Comment: @tiguero I don't think there's anything incompatible with the request and doing block-based animations. I suspect one could adapt my answer below if you want to use `CABasicAnimation`, too, if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop an animation, you can just do

```
[layer removeAllAnimations];
```

If you want to know the current `alpha` during the animated hiding of the view (so that you can reverse the animation, starting from the right place, you can do:

```
CALayer *presentationLayer = layer.presentationLayer;
CGFloat startingAlpha = presentationLayer.opacity;
```

You can then set the alpha to go from `startingAlpha` to 1.0 to animate the unhide without flickering the screen.

You can do the actual animations using block based animation, or I guess you could use `CABasicAnimation`, though I'm not sure why you would.

---

So, for example, you could do something like the following (in my example, I have a "show" button). I'm using block animations, but I suspect it would work fine for `CABasicAnimation`, too:

```
- (IBAction)onPressShowButton:(id)sender
{
    [self showAndScheduleHide];
}

- (void)showAndScheduleHide
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.containerView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self scheduleHide];
                     }];
}

- (void)show
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.containerView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

- (void)scheduleHide
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(startToHide)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
}

- (void)startToHide
{
    self.timer = nil;

    self.hiding = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         self.containerView.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.hiding = NO;
                     }];
}
```

You can then have some utility method for reversing it or rescheduling a hide in progress:

```
- (void)reverseAndPauseHide
{
    // if we have a "hide" scheduled, then cancel that

    if (self.timer)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }

    // if we have a hide in progress, then reverse it

    if (self.hiding)
    {
        [self.containerView.layer removeAllAnimations];

        CALayer *layer = self.containerView.layer.presentationLayer;
        CGFloat currentAlpha = layer.opacity;

        self.containerView.alpha = currentAlpha;

        [self show];
    }
}
```

Then, the question is when you know to call this `reverseAndPauseHide` and when to `scheduleHide` again. So, for example, you could handle touches:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [self reverseAndPauseHide];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    [self scheduleHide];
}
```